# difference between <text> and <span>

Tags: html, css

What the difference between them? Is the `<text>` even proper HTML tag? I've never seen the description of it on sites like http://www.w3schools.com/ but it seems to be working fine ( http://jsfiddle.net/qgaA2/ ) and I don't see any difference between it and `<span>`

Comment: Never use w3schools as the standard reference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it's not a real tag. The browser just looks at the attributes and makes the best of it.

This will work too: `<stupidtag style="color:red">moo</stupidtag>`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that `<text>` tag exists, and my reference is w3c.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure cross browser compatibility use the `<span>` tag. Not all browsers will recognize what to do with `<text>`.

Answer (score 0):

`<text>` tag does not exists, but the browsers displays anyway, just for the best compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

For a large amount of similar formatted text use <p> as it defines a paragraph. For special formatted text use <span>.